# Is the phrase "it shows" incomplete?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ellipsis

The headline from NY Times is:

> Liz Cheney Is Prepared to Lose Power, **and It Shows**

What does it shows? I read through it and it seemed to me the "it shows" phrase means the fact Liz Cheney Is Prepared to Lose Power is perceptible. But I'm not secure about my interpretation

Comment: My dog has been eating too much, and it shows.

Comment: Yes, "...and it shows" is a very common way of saying "and this fact is obvious".

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct.

"It shows" means "It's clear to see".

It comes from this definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show):

> **2 a :** to appear in a particular way